# Using TIA to pull FX rates from BBG?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, blpapi

I'm trying to use the TIA module to pull EURUSD forward rates from the BBG API?  How does one go about doing this?

I tried using the BbgDataManager() to specify a specific forward rate but don't seem to be having any success.  The code I tried is below.

```
df = mgr['EURUSD Curncy','FWD_CURVE'] 
df
MultiSidAccessor(EURUSD Curncy,FWD_CURVE)
df.FWD_CURVE
```

Produces the following error message:

File "", line 1
    df.EURUSD Curncy
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
df.FWD_CURVE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\anthony.yeh\PycharmProjects\blpapi\venv\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\datamgr.py", line 85, in **getattribute**
    return self.get_attributes(item, **self.overrides)
  File "C:\Users\anthony.yeh\PycharmProjects\blpapi\venv\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\datamgr.py", line 90, in get_attributes
    frame = self.mgr.get_attributes(self.sids, flds, **overrides)
  File "C:\Users\anthony.yeh\PycharmProjects\blpapi\venv\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\datamgr.py", line 148, in get_attributes
    return self.terminal.get_reference_data(sids, flds, **overrides).as_frame()
  File "C:\Users\anthony.yeh\PycharmProjects\blpapi\venv\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\v3api.py", line 745, in get_reference_data
    return self.execute(req)
  File "C:\Users\anthony.yeh\PycharmProjects\blpapi\venv\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\v3api.py", line 729, in execute
    request.has_exception and request.raise_exception()
  File "C:\Users\anthony.yeh\PycharmProjects\blpapi\venv\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\v3api.py", line 215, in raise_exception
    raise Exception('SecurityError: %s' % ','.join(msgs))
Exception: SecurityError: (FWD_CURVE, BAD_SEC, Unknown/Invalid Security  [nid:2972] )

Similarly, using the mgr with a query similar to the way you would pull this in Excel using BFxForward produces errors..

```
eurusd_sids = mgr["eurusd curncy","9/12/2019","midoutright"]\
eurusd_sids.PX_LAST
```

produces this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\anthony.yeh\PycharmProjects\blpapi\venv\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\datamgr.py", line 85, in **getattribute**
    return self.get_attributes(item, **self.overrides)
  File "C:\Users\anthony.yeh\PycharmProjects\blpapi\venv\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\datamgr.py", line 90, in get_attributes
    frame = self.mgr.get_attributes(self.sids, flds, **overrides)
  File "C:\Users\anthony.yeh\PycharmProjects\blpapi\venv\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\datamgr.py", line 148, in get_attributes
    return self.terminal.get_reference_data(sids, flds, **overrides).as_frame()
  File "C:\Users\anthony.yeh\PycharmProjects\blpapi\venv\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\v3api.py", line 745, in get_reference_data
    return self.execute(req)
  File "C:\Users\anthony.yeh\PycharmProjects\blpapi\venv\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\v3api.py", line 729, in execute
    request.has_exception and request.raise_exception()
  File "C:\Users\anthony.yeh\PycharmProjects\blpapi\venv\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\v3api.py", line 215, in raise_exception
    raise Exception('SecurityError: %s' % ','.join(msgs))
Exception: SecurityError: (9/12/2019, BAD_SEC, Unknown/Invalid Security  [nid:2972] ),(midoutright, BAD_SEC, Unknown/Invalid Security  [nid:2972] )

Answer (score 1):

You may try with `"EURUSD BGN Curncy"`